# How do I insert sysdate into a column using ODP and an XML dataset?

Tags: xml, oracle, odp.net

I'm using Oracle's ODP.Net to manipulate records.

When using the XML methods to insert and update records, I've run into a few problems.  When I am inserting a new record, I'd like the value of one of the columns to come from a sequence (MySeq.nextval).  I'd also like an UPDATE_DATE column to reflect sysdate.

I've only seen examples of OracleXmlCommand using completely formed Xml data sets to operate on.  I'd like to have some process-time updates included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DUH!  A trigger is exactly what this situation calls for.

- The key is using the index.  An Insert trigger can do this.
- Every time a record gets updated, the update date should be set.  Gee... maybe an Update trigger????